Invalid Switch case breaking flow on Ghidra
I'm using Ghidra to analyze an assembly code on HC11 core (old Motorola micros).
In a function where it apparently makes a switch case (image 1) if it loads value 0x00 to B register (0xddeb line), then the resulting value that will be added to Y pointer (line 0xddf7) will result in an out of boundary access (jmp to 0xde40 - see image 2 shows end of FUN_ddeb is 0xde3e).
Image 1:

Image 2:

Due to this, Ghidra is not able to disassembly this part and crashes:

I know this is a project bug, but as I'm assuming the programmer controls the value, but Ghidra doesn't see this way and crashes disassembly.
How can I solve this?
I tried patch 0xddf0 line with value 0x20 but doesn't work.

It does not "value 0x00 to B register", it loads indirectly from the address in X with an offset of zero.

Well, the disassemble is OK. Do you mean the decompiler? This looks like carefully hand-crafted assembler, so it is hard to decompile into C.

Did you try to limit the range of the value (stored in memory where X points to) used as index from 1 to 21 in Ghidra? I'm just a casual user, I have no actual idea about the options.

@thebusybee, Yeah, it loads indirectly from addr pointed by X with offset of zero! But if this value (pointed) is 0x00, then the math following will break!
You are right, my terminology is wrong! Disassembly is ok! Problem is Decompiler. I couldn't find a way to tell Ghidra the range of the value is limited....if this was possible I could skip zero for pointed value an limit to 0x20
